# How do I replace a variable that returns an empty value with a number value in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, structure

I'm putting together a batch file that can be dropped into a folder(named for each vendor) and create a folder structure based on the files inside and then move files into these folders.
The files are saved as pdfs or dwgs. Currently the script reads for pdfs only. 
File examples:
001.pdf
002-r1.pdf

The script reads the second file and creates the folder structure as 
002\REV 1 and then places the pdf in the last folder.

However when used for 001.pdf the folder structure is
001\REV 
How would I go about replacing the empty variable with a "0" or how would I change all the files in the folder into the same format XXX-rX.pdf

Thanks

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=-r,." %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do 
(


md %%a\"REV %%b" 2>nul
move "%%a*.pdf" "%%a\REV %%b"
)
```

Comment: The first `"` in the `md`statement is at the wrong position, but I think, that's a typo?

Comment: Yea doesn't make a difference where it is at the moment. Could be problematic for larger files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the information you have provided, test this:

```
ren ???.pdf ???-r1.pdf
```

Comment: Stephan- I got that. Thanks

Comment: Alright so new problem. When I have two files with the same file name but different revisions, it puts them both in the same revision folder. For example, 200-r0.pdf and 200-rA.pdf both go into the folder structure 200->REV 0. Is there some pause I'm missing or is my logic not correct for similar file names?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it. And added a timestamp and data logging text file.

```
@echo off
::create date variable
SET DayOfWeek=%Date:~0,3%
SET Day=%Date:~7,2%
SET Month=%Date:~4,2%
SET Year=%Date:~10,4%
SET Today=%Date:~4,2%/%Date:~7,2%/%Date:~10,4%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::rename pdfs without revisions
ren ???.pdf ???-r0.pdf

::for loop to create folder and move pdfs
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=-r,." %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (

md "%%a\REV %%b" 2>nul

move "%%a-r%%b.pdf" "%%a\REV %%b"




::write to file 
echo %%a,%%b,%TODAY%>>data.txt
)
```